# Is there a simple way to merge all glossaries to one index?

Tags: glossaries, indexing

I am using `glossaries` to make multiple lists of acronyms and symbols, and printing them before the main document. I would then like to print them all in an index after the main document, without the `type` titles and sorted together.

**EXAMPLE:**

---

**Symbols*

*c* Speed of light

*h* Planck's constant

**Acronyms**

**FPS**   Frames per second

*Main document*

**Index**

Frames per second (FPS) ............ p.1

Planck's constant (*h*) .................. p.2

Speed of light (*c*) ....................... p.3

---

My current **MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nomain, acronyms, nonumberlist, section=section]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add symbolslist


\glsaddkey{symbolvalue}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrysymbolvalue} {\GLsentrysymbolvalue}{\glssymbolvalue}{\Glssymbolvalue}{\GLSsymbolvalue}
\glssetnoexpandfield{symbolvalue}

\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package

\NewDocumentCommand{\newglossaryconstant}{o m m m m m}{\newglossaryentry{#2}{%
    name=\ensuremath{#3},
    description={#4},
    symbolvalue={#5},
    unit={#6},
    first={#4, (\ensuremath{#3})},
    text={\ensuremath{#3}},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#3}{#1}}}


\newglossaryconstant{lightspeed}{c}{speed of light}{299792432}{\si{\meter/\second}}

\newglossaryconstant[h]{planck}{h}{Planck's constant}{$6.6261\cdot10^{-34}$}{[\si{\joule\second}]}

\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fps}{FPS}{Frame per Second}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
% put the glossary in the itemize environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{.4\textwidth}>{\raggedleft}p{0.3\textwidth}r}}{\end{longtable}}%
% have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   Sign &  Description & Value & Unit \\
  \endhead}
% have nothing between glossary groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\vspace{-.5em}\\ \textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
% set how each entry should appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
  & \glssymbolvalue{##1}
  & \glsunit{##1}%
  \tabularnewline
}
}

\newglossarystyle{myindex}{%
\glossarystyle{mcolindexgroup}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
}


\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=mylist]   % list of symbols
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms

\glsresetall
\section{first}

\Gls{planck}

\subsection{second}
\Gls{planck}

\renewcommand{\glsmcols}{3}
\setglossarystyle{myindex}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Gives me this result:

[image]

Comment: Something like `\glsmoveentry` in conjunction with `\forallglsentries`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Thanks! I didn't realize that I was using an old version of the user manual, which doesn't include those functions.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, However, `\glsmoveentry` doesn't work inside the `document` and putting it in the preamble removes the entry from the original glossary. Also, I can't seem to get the entry to move to the glossary that I want, not sure if I'm using the wrong `<target glossary label>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `makeindex` to merge all the entries into a single file. If you remove the `nomain` option, you can use the `main` glossary for your combined index at the end and get `makeindex` to create a merged file.

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronyms, nonumberlist, section=section]{glossaries}% removed `nomain'
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{xparse}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add symbolslist


\glsaddkey{symbolvalue}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrysymbolvalue} {\GLsentrysymbolvalue}{\glssymbolvalue}{\Glssymbolvalue}{\GLSsymbolvalue}
\glssetnoexpandfield{symbolvalue}

\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package

\NewDocumentCommand{\newglossaryconstant}{o m m m m m}{\newglossaryentry{#2}{%
    name=\ensuremath{#3},
    description={#4},
    symbolvalue={#5},
    unit={#6},
    first={#4, (\ensuremath{#3})},
    text={\ensuremath{#3}},
    type=symbolslist,
    sort=\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#3}{#1}}}


\newglossaryconstant{lightspeed}{c}{speed of light}{299792432}{\si{\meter/\second}}

\newglossaryconstant[h]{planck}{h}{Planck's constant}{$6.6261\cdot10^{-34}$}{[\si{\joule\second}]}

\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fps}{FPS}{Frame per Second}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
% put the glossary in the itemize environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{.4\textwidth}>{\raggedleft}p{0.3\textwidth}r}}{\end{longtable}}%
% have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   Sign &  Description & Value & Unit \\
  \endhead}
% have nothing between glossary groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\vspace{-.5em}\\ \textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
% set how each entry should appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
  & \glssymbolvalue{##1}
  & \glsunit{##1}%
  \tabularnewline
}
}

\newglossarystyle{myindex}{%
\setglossarystyle{mcolindexgroup}% changed \glossarystyle to \setglossarystyle
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
}


\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=mylist]   % list of symbols
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms

\glsresetall
\section{first}

\Gls{planck}

\subsection{second}
\Gls{planck}

\renewcommand{\glsmcols}{3}
\setglossarystyle{myindex}

\printglossary[title=Index]% main glossary
\end{document}
```

(Note: `\glossarystyle` is deprecated. I've replaced it with `\setglossarystyle`. If this new command isn't recognised, then I recommend you update your version of `glossaries`. Incidentally, you can just use `mcolindex`, which is functionally identical to your `myindex` style.)

If the file is called `test.tex`, then the build process is:

```
pdflatex test
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.slg -o test.syi test.syg
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.alg -o test.acr test.acn
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.glg -o test.gls test.acn test.syg
pdflatex test
```

The third `makeindex` call merges `test.acn` (acronyms) and `test.syg` (symbols) and saves the result to `test.gls` (main).

[image: image of document]